# ajax pass array to wcf service

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

having problem in, from table i get data and passed it to wcf web service

first service

```
public string SaveDate(string data) {
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List < string[] > mystring = json.Deserialize < List < string[] >> (data);
    return "saved";
}
```

Second get data and ajax call

```
    $('#btnPaymentOk').click(function () {
        var objList = new Array();
        $("table#tblGridProductInformation > tbody > tr").each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('td.Qty').text() != '') {
                objList.push(new Array($(this).find('td.LocalSalesPrice').text(), $(this).find('td.Total').text()));
                //objList.push(new Array("a", "b"));
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/WebPOSService.svc/SaveDate",
            data: "{data:" + JSON.stringify(objList) + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });

    });
```

in pass look like

```
{data:[["1.00","1.00"],["0.60","0.60"],["0.40","0.40"]]}
```

json array

problem is not get data from service end

help me out

Comment: inspect the request in browser console network tab. Need a lot more information

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataContract:

```
[DataContract]
public class Data
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<string[]> data { get; set; }
}
```

Here's code I used to test it, and it worked.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Data
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<string[]> data { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonTxt = "{data:[[\"1.00\",\"1.00\"],[\"0.60\",\"0.60\"],[\"0.40\",\"0.40\"]]}";
            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(jsonTxt);

            //Use this if you don't want to use DataContract, but you will have to reference Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
            List<string[]> fullDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[]>>(JObject.Parse(jsonTxt)["data"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I would recommend you use [Newtonsoft](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/598599) library for serializing/deserializing JSON data. Don't forget to add a framework reference to [System.Runtime.Serializiation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you haven't already.

Comment: having problem with the jquery .. i m not trying to use this in c# code.